# Deep custom AngularJS Filter

Tags: javascript, angular.js, underscore.js

I need to filter projects using a searchbar, it should filter all properties of the projects with a few exceptions. It's working, but it's extremely slow, where can I make optimizations?
The "_" is from the library underscore.js

```
<div class="fixed-header">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="form-control" placeholder="Suche..."/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="initial" 
        ng-repeat-start="(customer, projectGroup) in projects | searchProjects:searchText">
       {{customer}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the filter:

```
.filter('searchProjects', ($rootScope, $filter) => {
    return (projects, query) => {
        if (projects) {
            var passFilter = projects.filter(p => {
                let backUpContacts = false;
                if (p) {

                    //If project has customer and customer has references, don't search in all of them
                    if (p.kunde && p.kunde.contacts) {
                        backUpContacts = p.kunde.contacts.concat([]);
                        //Only leave the selected Reference Contact in Customer's Contacts for Search
                        p.kunde.contacts = p.kunde.contacts.filter(contact => p.reference === contact.id);
                    }

                    //Search also for project leaders that have to be found first
                    let projectLeaders = [];
                    $rootScope.profiles.forEach(profile => {
                        profile.projects.forEach(role => {
                            if (role.project === p.id) {
                                let projectRole = role.masterData['Projektrolle'];
                                if (projectRole && ~projectRole.indexOf(864)) {
                                    projectLeaders.push(profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    p["projectLeaders"] = projectLeaders;
                }
                let pContain = _.contains($filter('filter')(projects, query), p);
                delete p["projectLeaders"];
                if (backUpContacts) {
                    p.kunde.contacts = backUpContacts;
                }
                return pContain;
            });
            return passFilter;
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to improve it myself and it is much faster than before!
Here's my new code, feel free to comment on what can be further done to improve it.

```
    .filter('searchProjects', ($rootScope, $filter) => {
        return (projects, query) => {
            if (projects) {
                //Create project leader search object
                let projectLeaders = {};
                $rootScope.profiles.forEach(profile => {
                    profile.projects.forEach(role => {
                        let projectRole = role.masterData['Projektrolle'];
                        //864 = Projectleader Tag ID
                        if (projectRole && ~projectRole.indexOf(864)) {
                            let projectLeader = profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName;
                            if (projectLeaders.hasOwnProperty(role.project)) {
                                projectLeaders[role.project].push(projectLeader);
                            } else {
                                projectLeaders[role.project] = [projectLeader];
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                return projects.filter(p => {
                    //delete customers' contacts to exclude from search
                    if (p.kunde && p.kunde.contacts) {
                        //Only leave the selected Reference Contact in Customer's Contacts for Search
                        p.kunde.contacts = p.kunde.contacts.filter(contact => p.reference === contact.id);
                    }
                    //if project has leaders, add them to it for searching
                    if (projectLeaders.hasOwnProperty(p.id)) {
                        p["projectLeaders"] = projectLeaders[p.id];
                    }
                    return Boolean($filter('filter')([p], query).length);
                });
            }
        };
    })
```